# php array_keys returns [0,1] but array[1] throws undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, offset, explode

I used the explode function to create and array this array is actually supposed to have two elements after the explode I checked with the count function and it does contain 2 elements, I also printed a json of the array and it contains two elements finally I used array keys and it returned [0,1] but array[1] throws undefined offset... Please help

## Code

```
   $name = $request['name'];
        $exercises = $request['video_exercises'];
        $custom_names = $request['video_custom_names'];
        $custom_names = explode('-', $custom_names);
        $exercises = explode('-', $exercises);
        $set = new Set();
        try {
           $set->name = $name;
           $set->save();    
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {

            return ['success'=>false,'message'=>'An unexpected error occured, a different may be using the same name you are trying to use'.$ex->getMessage()];
        }
        foreach ($exercises as $exercise) {
            $temp = new Exercise();
            $custom_name = '';
            foreach ($custom_names as $name) {
                if($name!=='')
                if (explode($exercise, $name)!== false) {
                    $temp_name = explode('+', $name);
                    $custom_name = $temp_name[1]; //Returns undefined offset
                } 
            }
```

Comment: can you provide the actual contents of `$custom_names`

Comment: Maybe is an associative array, why don't you check the array using a `var_dump` over `$custom_names`?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I have edited the question, it now shows the roots of custom_names

Comment: What is the exact output of: `highlight_string(print_r($yourArray, TRUE));` when you take the output from the source code? Please add that to your question.